# Unity использование библиотек в обычном коде

Tags: c#, unity3d

Можно ли использовать using Unity и using UnityEngine в обычном проекте вне Unity? Как это сделать?

Comment: Скопировать нужные dll файлы из проекта юнити в свой проект и залинковать их в настройках проекта.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите сделать свой движок или в программе то у вас не получиться так как все API действуют на движок Unity. Но вы можете создавать плагины для Unity.